# Python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded vs code in my windows 10 computer just, I want to learn python in it.
So, I have installed some extensions like "Python" , "Python
for VSCode" ,"code runner".
But when I click on the <kbd>run</kbd> button (Ctrl+ALT+N)
I am getting this error in my terminal:

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -u "e:\C File\Source file\practice.py"
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But when I type `py -u "e:\C File\Source file\practice.py"`
instead of `python -u "e:\C File\Source file\practice.py"`
it is working,

Now what should I do to run this at one mouse click, I don't want to run the code by typing the command.

Comment: Looks like the  "Python for VSCode" extension is not installed properly. A workaround might be to configure vscode to use the `py` command instead of `python` to run the Python scripts.

Comment: add python to PATH

Comment: what is this command `py` you use on the command line, it is not the default exe name. give the full name of the extenstions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, most likely your 'Python' global environment variable is not set correctly.

But, since you mention that `py -u [File Path]` command seems to give you the output I can suggest that you change how "Code Runner" extension sends a Run command.

Steps:

1. Click File>Preferences>Settings (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Open "settings.json" file (refer to my attached GIF file for reference)
3. Paste the following code lines at the end of this file ensuring you don't miss any commas (again refer to the attached GIF):

   ```
   "code-runner.executorMap": {
   "python": "py -u",
   },
   ```

This should change how the Code-Runner extension sends the Run Code command for Python files. Save the `settings.json` file and try running your code again using the same shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>".

Does this fix your issue, Pranav?  If not, maybe post a clipping of the error message again.

[Link to the GIF file showing how to insert the code in settings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEggR.gif)